# Is the evaluation order of dynamic array elements guaranteed?

Tags: javascript, syntax, semantics

I tried to find a concise way to move the final element of an array to the first position, and came up with a one line solution `pop`ping the element and spreading into the array:

```js
arr1 = [arr1.pop(), ...arr1];
```

My question is this: is the order of evaluation here guaranteed, across browsers?

I ask because if `...arr1` is evaluated *before* `arr1.pop()`, then the array will end up with a copy of the same element at the beginning and the end (eg. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`).

I understand that in Javascript, evaluation is always done linearly from left to right, which makes sense in expressions and function arg lists. What I can't find is whether concurrent array elements count toward this linear nature, or whether there's a chance that they could be evaluated concurrently (or whether it's left to be implementation dependent by the standard).

Comment: yes, it is guaranteed.  especially in this case.  rest operator can't evaluate until the value of arr1.pop() is evaluated, since it has to populate the array

Comment: Where is this being called? Is the function asynchronous? Could you provide a larger code snippet if possible?

Comment: right, if arr.pop() was [async_pop_func(arr1), ...arr1], that would be different.  Then the pop can evaluate later.  Which doesn't apply to what OP is asking.  @Dom I think zcoop98 is probably hoping for a walkthrough of ES specs that explicitly proves/guarantees that evaluation order is guaranteed when assignment and mutation is all on a one line statement.  Which does exist, but requires a full write up and explanation of relevant specs for syntax interpretation

Comment: You can also use `splice/pop` like so: `arr.splice(0, 0, arr.pop());` (without assigning back to `arr`)

Comment: @Dom I *can* add some extra context, but I don't think it's super relevant to my question, however. My use case is checking arrays that represent a hand of playing cards, looking for a specific case, the 5-high straight, where sorting by value has yielded the wrong order (with Ace at the end rather than the beginning). To fix it, I need to move the last element to the start of the array, that's what spawned this question.

Comment: since you're okay with mutating the array, arr.unshift(arr.pop()) would have been easier.  if immutability is needed [x[x.length-1],...x.slice(0,-1)]

Comment: "exchange the first and last elements in an array" - that's not what your code does, though. Exchanging the first and last elements of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` would give `[5, 2, 3, 4, 1]`, while your code produces `[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overview of syntax to get a bird's eye view: [Array Initializer Syntax](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ArrayLiteral)

*(note: In the below, I've excluded Elision_opt from the grammar for brevity, which accounts for consecutive commas or commas without a preceding defined element to allow for empty elements,

eg: `[el1,,el2]=[el1,(empty),el2]`)*

First, as per [12.2.5.2 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

`[ arr1.pop(), ...arr1 ]`
`[ ElementList         ]`

[12.2.5.1 Runtime Semantics: ArrayAccumulation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation):
               `arr1.pop() ,   ...arr1`
`ElementList:   ElementList,   SpreadElement`

> 1. Set nextIndex to the result of performing ArrayAccumulation for ElementList with arguments array and nextIndex.

[...]

> 4. Return the result of performing ArrayAccumulation for SpreadElement with arguments array and nextIndex.

Thus at Step 1. `ArrayAccumulation` must be performed on `arr1.pop()`, before it evaluates `...arr1`.  You will notice that in this case the evaluation of the `SpreadElement` even depends on the value of `nextIndex` derived from calling `ArrayAccumulation` on the first part.  And that the syntax evaluation recurses in such a way that it is evaluated from left to right, branching off the parts on the right.
(This is just a feature of the grammar parsing.)
Note also that:
`ElementList: ElementList, AssignmentExpression` and
`ElementList: ElementList, ...AssignmentExpression` are structured in the same way.

*(Note: the above is already proof of the guaranteed evaluation order)*
The rest of the evaluation goes as thus:
             `arr1.pop()`
`ElementList: AssignmentExpression`

> 4. Let created be ! CreateDataPropertyOrThrow(array, ! ToString(nextIndex), initValue).
> 5. Return nextIndex + 1.

And so `SpreadElement` `ArrayAccumulation` is called on `arr1` next with parameters array with `arr1.pop()`'s return value inserted and `nextIndex + 1`
SpreadElement ArrayAccumulation, roughly summarized, gets an iterator on `arr1` (`AssignmentExpression`), iterates on it, and:

> d. Perform ! CreateDataPropertyOrThrow(array, ! ToString(nextIndex), nextValue).

on each iterated value.